# How can I create a map which highlights specified categories (example, "Malls") for large format printing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, maps

How do I create a map where I can highlight or toggle certain categories or features (Malls, major roads etc.)

Needs:

1. Export to vector
2. Re-edit (lines and shapes)

ADD: I have Illustrator.

**The map will be a 2x2 meter print.**

Thank you!

Tried Snazzymaps - Great color customizability. But no vector export.

Comment: You could try something like OpenStreetMap. Find the area you want, and use the Share button to download the SVG, and edit it with a vector image editor like Illustrator (paid software) or Inkscape (free and Open Source).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Billy. Yeah I know OpenStreetMap and I have Illustrator. My problem with OpenStreetMap (for now) is there are many extraneous elements on there. I cant toggle elements on or off and show just the malls :'/ I'm still exploring though. Maybe it can be extensively customized (to be as simple or complicated as wanted)

Comment: This just seems like a shopping list question to me.

Comment: What, Scott? ;'DD Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean it's a shopping list. It's a detailed list of requirements for my needs. If I don't mention details, someone will ask me for details. So there, details.

Comment: Update: I used a Google Maps data scraper (used Outscraper - keywords: Mall, Plaza, Square) to export the mall locations into a CSV. (Since most map services can import CSV.) Now trying out different map creation online services to create my map. Still no luck with a good enough service. Either very expensive or simply cannot export (Export error! using Datawrapper.de).

Comment: Your comment just cements my perception.. this is a shopping list question  [Read up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed) this could not more clearly be a shopping list question - even if I do know an answer it's irrelevant - it doesn't make the question on-topic.

Comment: Ohh, so there is such a thing. So when a question is hard to answer (and a variation of "What's the best..."), and there are criteria to answer it, it's shopping list?
So I'll change my question from "What's the easiest" to "How can I..."
Anyway, yes my problem is hard, that's why I needed to ask it here. Didn't realize how hard it was until I asked it here. There's not one way to answer it obviously :') which is the way with a lot of softwares and workflows. Anyway, I'll probably post a Question-Answer here for how I solved my problem.

Comment: Shopping list: Find this for me......

Comment: Shopping lists?
"What is the most accurate cheap way of repeatably measuring out small quantities of compressible powder?"
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/126579/what-is-the-most-accurate-cheap-way-of-repeatably-measuring-out-small-quantities
---
How can I measure / weigh really small quantities?
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83214/how-can-i-measure-weigh-really-small-quantities

Comment: last I checked this wasn't cooking.se.

Comment: You can check again, please. It's still stack exchange. Now I've changed the question and details to be not a shopping list. And I'm cooking a map :'). Would appreciate your help for the steps on how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, depending on how large is the area you're trying to capture (a few blocks? a whole city?) it might be faster to just get the map from sources mentioned in other comments/answers and highlight the categories manually.

Answer (score 1):

The question has gradually evolved to "How I can create..."

Originally it was more like "From where I can pick a map where certain item classes (malls, roads, highways,hospitals, graveyards, jails...) are clearly separated from each other so that I can change their colors and make other edits - preferably a free or low cost pick and vector format, thank you!"

Your local city authorities surely have one. Except in case they just want to buy it from you.

Open street map is the free source for the base map. Google can sell rights for certain purposes. But from where to pick the current details, for example which buildings are malls just today and how to get them marked to a new layer?

I'm afraid you must still buy the information like you have previously done or get it from the local authorities as text or map, even as in a perfect vector format, if you are lucky and draw or paste it to the base map as a new layer by yourself. The previous version probably knows quite a big percentage of the things, but not all.

There's some heavy duty trickery to be learned. Editing downloaded Open Street maps is one of them. For many purposes it's much easier to draw all items manually and to use open Street Map only as a guide. Often the drawn items can be drastically simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that this question still feels a little off-topic to me - but that said, I'd look into QGIS for this sort of task.

It's a bit like ESRI's ArcGIS, but open-source, a bit... woolier, but super-effective and extensible to do SO many things. And... excels at Map creation with specific criteria.

Use it medium-frequently, and have long since removed ESRI from my machines and use solely QGIS for my GIS needs.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/

My two cents.

[Map Example 01](https://www.flickr.com/photos/city-planner/42809689140/in/pool-2327386@N22)

[Map Example 02](https://www.flickr.com/photos/drakesprague/48685270827/in/pool-2327386@N22)